# How to select a word under cursor?

Tags: editors, select

For all text editor or application I'm using, I want to select a word under cursor using keyboard shortcut.

How can I do it?
I tried look around I didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 6):

In `vim`, `viw` (view inside word) enters visual mode and selects the word under the cursor, though in `vi` typical usage pattern, you'd rather do things like `diw` (delete inside word), or `ciw` (change inside word) to change it rather than first select it and do something on it.

Change `w` to `W` to switch to whitespace delimited *words*, `i` to `a` (*view a word*) to also include the surrounding whitespace in the selection.

Replace `iw`/`aw` with `2iw`/`2aw` to select two words, etc.

You can also always use `b` to move to the start of the word and then to `ce`, `de`, `ve` to change/delete/view up to the end of the word or `cw`, `dw`, `vw` to the word (similar kind of distinction as in between `iw` and `aw`). Those (as opposed to `iw`/`aw` which are `vim` extensions) are standard `vi` operators.

Run `:h iw` or `:h aw` or more generally `:h motion.txt` for details on those motion operators.

That's also available in the line editor of the `zsh` shell, when in `vi` mode (`bindkey -v` to switch to `vi` mode from the `emacs` mode).

Answer (score 1):

There’s no universal single shortcut to do this, however many applications support shortcuts to move the cursor while tracking word boundaries, and select. Using arrow-based key combinations, you should find that <kbd>Ctrl <kbd>←</kbd></kbd> will move to the start of the current word (or the previous word, if the cursor is already at the start of the current word), and then <kbd>Ctrl <kbd>Shift <kbd>→</kbd></kbd></kbd> will select the current word.

Some applications use different shortcuts for the above. For example, Emacs supports the arrow-based key combinations now, but historically Emacs users would use <kbd>Meta <kbd>B</kbd></kbd> (`M-b`), <kbd>Ctrl <kbd>Space</kbd></kbd> (`C-SPC`), and <kbd>Meta <kbd>F</kbd></kbd> (`M-f`).

Comment: ctrl space and navigation key yeah but a bit inconvenient. Thank you